# Mexico Permanent Residency requirements when minor turns 18

Tags: residency, children, mexico

We have recently become permanent residents of Mexico (having lived here for the required 4 years as temporary residents).  So recent, in fact, that we're still waiting on the new ID cards.

We had one question for INM that we have asked them twice now, however both times we feel the answer (or perhaps our question?) has got a little lost in translation, and so we don't really understand the requirements.

We have 4 kids, 3 of them are minors - two teens and a pre-teen.  Their PR was applied under our names as parents, so we asked what they'd need to do when they turn 18 - did they need to apply for their own PR, or change their PR status from minor to adult, or not worry about doing anything.

The answer we got (which we're not sure we understand) was that the older two (who will turn 18 within 4 years) just apply for a new card in 4 years which would just cost a card replacement fee of about $1400 MXN each.  But the youngest would need to reapply every 4 years until he turns 18, at an application cost of $5000 MXN each time.  This doesn't make sense to me (several parts of it), so I'm wondering if anyone can provide a proper explanation or their own similar experience?

Do our children need to reapply for Permanent Residency in their own right (ie their own application showing their own income etc. etc., or is it just a change of status from minor to adult?  And why would the fees be different for the younger?  They seem backward to me.

If it makes any difference we are New Zealand citizens.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer, I am in the same boat?
Thanks